# Ajax cant load php json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, sjax

The Problem is, the **json** file is not showing. Im using **Xampp** as local Server.

php file:

```
$array = array(
  array(
    "title" => "Erster Eintrag",
    "description" => "Description",
    "link" => "http://",
    "pubDate" => "02.07.2015"
  ),
  array(
    "title" => "Zweiter Eintrag",
    "description" => "Description",
    "link" => "http://",
    "pubDate" => "02.07.2015"
  )      
);
echo json_encode($json);
```

html file:

```
$ajax({
url:'localhost/uebung/staticfeed.php',
type:'POST',
data:'data',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(result){
  $('#feeds').html(result[0]);
}
})
```

Comment: Do you json_encode the php before echoing or what you're doing ?

Comment: What happens when you load `localhost/uebung/staticfeed.php`? If nothing, then it's your server config. If you get back an array, you need to `json_encode()` the data, and set the header to the json type.

Comment: im using json_encode(). With localhost/uebung/staticfeed.php i get the json perfectly shown.

Comment: I'm thinking @Lylo might have the right answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP

> Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.

Use `$array` to `json_encode` instead of `$json`.

```
echo json_encode($array);
///             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I have, just forgot to write it.

Comment: @FreshManu Check updated answer. Notice `Use $array to json_encode instead of $json.`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript use $.ajax and then full URL.

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://localhost/uebung/staticfeed.php',
type:'POST',
data:'data',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(result){
  $('#feeds').html(result[0]);
});
```

You also need to encode your array in your php file.

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$ajax` to `$.ajax`, this will remove the error in your code, everything else works fine

Answer (score 1):

You are missing JSON headers in your PHP answer, Jquery may interpret your response as plain text or HTML...

Also, you are echoing `$json` and your array is `$array`.

Try this for PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$array = [["title" => "Erster Eintrag","description" => "Description","link" => "http://","pubDate" => "02.07.2015"],["title" => "Zweiter Eintrag","description" => "Description","link" => "http://","pubDate" => "02.07.2015"]];
echo json_encode($array);
```

And this on your HTML:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "localhost/uebung/staticfeed.php", data:data, dataType: "json", timeout: 25000, success: function (result) {
 $('#feeds').html('First array:' + result.[0].title + '<br />Seccond array:' + result.[1].title );
}});
```

You need to select the value INSIDE the array inside [result]...

Comment: In this case, since the `$.ajax()` call explicitly lists `dataType: 'json'`, there should not be risk of jQuery interpreting this as something other than JSON, but I am giving +1 as the OP should provide appropriate Content-type header as you mention. This is just a best practice.

Comment: Thing is... as we are calling for a json file jQuery can interpret the answer as anything else which ends up beign an error because "is not" JSON. On the other hand if we don't define JSON at the ajax call then jQuery will handle that response the best way it can instead of sending it to error. Thanks.